# forward_list::remove throwing compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I have the following code:

```
typedef std::forward_list<RdidSettings> RdidList;
RdidList m_rdids;

//ctor for RdidSettings 
RdidSettings(_In_ const GUID& rdid, _In_ bool isDr) throw() :


//Add to rdidlist method 
RdidSettings& AddRdid(  _In_ const GUID& rdid,  _In_ bool isDr  ) 
{   
    m_rdids.emplace_front(rdid, isDr);  return m_rdids.front(); 
}


//method for rdid list method 
void RemoveRdid( _In_  RdidSettings& rdidData) 
{   
    m_rdids.remove(rdidData); <<-- whats wrong with this remove ? 
}
```

The moment I introduce the remove method I start getting compiler error :

> forward_list(1281) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found
>   which takes a left-hand operand of type RdidSettings' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion) could be 'bool std::operator ==(const
>   std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) throw()'
>
> 'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const
>   std::error_code &) throw()' 6> \sdk\inc\ucrt\stl120\system_error(406):
>   or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const
>   std::error_condition &) throw()' 6> \sdk\inc\ucrt\exception(333): or
>   'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t)' 6>
>   \sdk\inc\ucrt\exception(328): or       'bool std::operator
>   ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &)' 6> \sdk\inc\ucrt\exception(323): or       'bool std::operator ==(const
>   std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)' 6> while trying to
>   match the argument list '(RdidSettings, const RdidSettings)' 6>
>   \sdk\inc\ucrt\stl120\forward_list(1276) : while compiling class
>   template member function 'void
>   std::forward_list>::remove(const _Ty
>   &)' 6> with 6> [ 6> _Ty=RdidSettings 6> ] 6> hostsettings.cpp(65) :
>   see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::forward_list>::remove(const _Ty
>   &)' being compiled 6> with 6> [ 6> _Ty=RdidSettings 6> ] 6>
>   \hostsettings.h(181) : see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::forward_list>' being compiled
>   6> with 6> [ 6> _Ty=RdidSettings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you don't provide `operator==` for `RdidSettings`.

Comment: Thanks, what does that mean ? You mean implement an overload for == .

Comment: @confusednerd, you need to provide operator==, so you can compare two  RdidSettings objects.